# How to create successive layers of Hexagonal Closed Packing?

Tags: packing-problem

[image: Hexagonal Closed Packing]

How do I create a HCP using the bottom A layer? In other words, if I take the first layer and make a second layer, how much do I shift it vertically (z direction) and how much do I shift it backwards and forwards (along y axis) each time I make a new layer? In terms of *r*, the radius of a sphere, would be best.

Answer (score 0):

If we pick any sphere in the bottom layer and an adjacent sphere in the layer above, the displacement vector between their centers tells us how to translate the bottom layer in 3-space to the layer above.

For simplicity, let's pick three adjacent spheres whose centers are nicely situated in the $xy$-plane. Specifically, let one be at the origin $(0,0,0)$, another at $(2,0,0)$, and a third at $(1,\sqrt{3},0)$. (It is well-known that if you cut an equilateral triangle in half, you get a $1$-$\sqrt{3}$-$2$ triangle.)

This triangle sits at the base of a pyramid (regular tetrahedron), the top vertex of which is the center of a sphere in the above layer that is adjacent to the original three.

**Exercise**. Repeatedly use the Pythagorean theorem to show the centroid of the equilateral triangle must be $(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0)$ and the top vertex of the tetrahedron is $(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}})$.

You can also figure out the angles between various features of this pyramid.